# When SIP ALG is disabled in routers, no SIP packets are routed

Tags: sip, router, nat, stun

I am developing STUN for VoIP behind NAT(SIP protocol)..
I have a couple of routers for use..I find that the routers are changing the SIP messages(SDP and contact field)for NAT traversal...**If I disable SIP ALG in routers,then NO SIP packets are forwarded**..Is there any setting so that the Routers don't put any SIP intelligence and just forward the packets and not change the sip packet.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Router model is important. Some of them known are not SIP friendly. Though I never seen a router that wouldn't forward TCP/UDP to 5060 when SIP ALG is disabled. I presume you're developing STUN client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy a new router.  Seriously, any NAT existing in 2013 that is still trying to translate application protocols (other than FTP) and modifying message contents (beyond the IP header) should be thrown out.

Is your SIP traffic sent over TCP or UDP?  Is there a SIP gateway involved?  Or are you trying to do a SIP INVITE between two endpoints without a signaling server?

In any case.... the standard solution to this problem is that the SIP messages should be sent over TLS/SSL (encrypted) to the SIP gateway. Your router won't be able to interpret these messages and will just treat them as a standard TCP traffic.

If you code for both endpoints, a simpler fix is to simply base64 encode your messages

Comment: There is a SIP server in the middle but settings have been enabled in the server not to make any change in SIP packets.